# Setting custom TextInput into Flext/Spark ComboBox

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, textinput, flex-spark

Is there a way to set my custom made TextInput component (call it CustomTextInput) as textInput property of ComboBox?

I've tried something like this:

```
<s:ComboBox id="myCombo" dataProvider="{myDP}">
    <s:textInput>
        <components:CustomTextInput />
    </s:textInput>
</s:ComboBox>
```

It doesn't work, but it could illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You'll have to create a custom skin

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by editing the MXML file for the following ActionScript, Flex, spark only combo box which is available [open source](https://github.com/pdpsolutions/px/blob/master/visual/BindableComboBox.mxml) (only one MXML file to edit, so it is simpler than editing <s:ComboBox>).